# Can we be more careful while approving edits on answers?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I had posted an answer which I thought would help the OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20595307/revisions). Later a user suggested an edit to the answer and someone approved it which totally changed the answer.

It's about a default IP address which was entered in the answer as for some it will be *192.168.1.X* as well. And if it's connected on Wi-Fi you can't tell for sure if it's going to be the same IP every time as well as it gets changed on every reconnect.

Comment: Wow, **three users unanimously approved that**??? That's terrible... I am commenting to all three of them right now

Comment: Those users don't have a lot of rep on the tags on that question. They must have felt very confident... I wouldn't....

Comment: This **must** not happen! It's not like the answer is Community Wiki to edit to such extent.

FWIW the editor must have made a separate answer to the question of his own.

Comment: Sympathy upvotes. In reality, not much we can do at the current time, unless you have a particular suggestion?

Comment: yes, that's not good. And now? Adding more audits?

Comment: Well, *at least* the OP caught this and rolled it back.  Still, that doesn't solve the problem itself.  Something tells me that edit was approved because the reviewers found the edited-in information to be correct.  Assuming they weren't just robo-reviewing, they need to be aware that any edits like that, even if the new information is 100% correct, should be rejected with the appropriate rejection reason to (hopefully) educate the editor.